# First route of a lazy loaded module cannot be reached

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I have two routing modules first one app-routing-module which is the main one, and I'm trying to lazy load recipes module, in total I have 6 modules, I will provide all of them, I get this error:  Error: NG04007: The Router was provided more than once. This can happen if 'forRoot' is used outside of the root injector. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.when I try to reach recipes path, even though I used RouterModule.forChild() in recipes-routing-module.

AppModule:

```
import { ShoppingListModule } from './shopping-list.module';
import { RecipesModule } from './recipes.module';
import { AuthInterceptorService } from './services/auth-interceptor.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AuthComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RecipesModule,
    ShoppingListModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  providers: [{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptorService, multi: true}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AppRoutingModule:

```
import { ErrorPageComponent } from './error-page/error-page.component';
import { ShoppingListComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent },
  { path: 'not-found', component: ErrorPageComponent, data: { message: 'Page Not Found' } },
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent },
  { path: 'recipes', loadChildren: () => import('./recipes.module').then(m => m.RecipesModule) }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

RecipesRoutingModule:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CreateRecipeComponent } from './recipes/create-recipe/create-recipe.component';
import { RecipesDetailComponent } from './recipes/recipes-detail/recipes-detail.component';
import { RecipesComponent } from './recipes/recipes.component';
import { CanActivateGuardService } from './services/guards/can-activate-guard.service';
import { CanDeactivateGuardService } from './services/guards/can-deactivate-guard.service';
import { RecipesResolverService } from './services/guards/recipes-resolver.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RecipesComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'create-recipe',
        component: CreateRecipeComponent,
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuardService],
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: RecipesDetailComponent,
        resolve: [RecipesResolverService],
      },
      {
        path: ':id/edit',
        component: CreateRecipeComponent,
        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuardService],
        resolve: [RecipesResolverService],
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'recipes-list',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class RecipesRoutingModule {}
```

SharedModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DropdownDirective } from './directives/dropdown.directive';
import { ErrorPageComponent } from './error-page/error-page.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { PlaceholderDirective } from './directives/placeholder.directive';
import { ErrorModalComponent } from './reuseable/components/error-modal/error-modal.component';
import { LoadingSpinnerComponent } from './reuseable/components/spinner/loading-spinner/loading-spinner.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    DropdownDirective,
    NotFoundComponent,
    ErrorPageComponent,
    LoadingSpinnerComponent,
    ErrorModalComponent,
    PlaceholderDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
    DropdownDirective,
    NotFoundComponent,
    ErrorPageComponent,
    LoadingSpinnerComponent,
    ErrorModalComponent,
    PlaceholderDirective,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

RecipesModule:

```
import { RecipesRoutingModule } from './recipes-routing.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CreateRecipeComponent } from './recipes/create-recipe/create-recipe.component';
import { RecipesDetailComponent } from './recipes/recipes-detail/recipes-detail.component';
import { RecipeItemComponent } from './recipes/recipes-list/recipe-item/recipe-item.component';
import { RecipesListComponent } from './recipes/recipes-list/recipes-list.component';
import { RecipesComponent } from './recipes/recipes.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RecipesComponent,
    RecipesListComponent,
    RecipesDetailComponent,
    RecipeItemComponent,
    CreateRecipeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RecipesRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  // exports: [
  //   RecipesComponent,
  //   RecipesListComponent,        //Because now we load these components internaly via routing(in the recipeRoutingModule) we dont need to export the components
  //   RecipesDetailComponent,
  //   RecipeItemComponent,
  //   CreateRecipeComponent
  // ]
})
export class RecipesModule { }
```

ShoppingListModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ShoppingListComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';
import { ShoppingListEditComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list-edit/shopping-list-edit.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ShoppingListComponent, ShoppingListEditComponent],
  imports: [SharedModule],
  exports: [ShoppingListComponent, ShoppingListEditComponent]
})
export class ShoppingListModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the errors states, you're importing twice the `RouterModule.forRoot()`.

You import it in your `AppRoutingModule`. Then, you're importing `AppRoutingModule` in both `AppModule` and `SharedModule`.

In your AppModule, you're actually importing `SharedModule`  (which imports itself `AppRoutingModule`) and `AppRoutingModule`.

You should import your routes only once. You should remove `AppRoutingModule` from your `SharedModule`.